# Brownian motion motivation of construction

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have read Stochastic Differential Equations by Bernt Oksendal
It constructs Brownian motion by Kolmogorov extension theorem by consider $p(t,x,y)=(2\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{- \frac{|x-y|^{2}}{2t}}$
Why Brownian motion is construct in such way? Why  such $p(t,x,y)$ is considered. Why this construction can model Brownian motion.
I had asked the same question but somebdy migrate my question to physics SE.I can't delet it  so I modify my question and ask again.Please don't move it to somewhere else. I do ask these in mathematics meaning.

Comment: Why are you not answering the query made on physics.SE to understand your question? Kind of rude, don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to the density is by trying to model Brownian motion as the limit of random walks. I will keep it informal about the kind of convergence we get and for which kinds of steps these are valid.

Let's suppose you have a random walk that is given by $W_{k\Delta t} = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ where every step $X_i$ is independent of each other and has variance $\sigma^2$. That means that 
$$
\text{Var} \,W_{k\Delta t} = k \,\sigma^2
$$
which means that:
$$
\text{Var} \frac{W_{k\Delta t}}{\sqrt{k}} = \sigma^2
$$

Now we take the limit $k\to\infty$, and $k\Delta t \to s$, we get a variable:
$$
B_s = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{W_{k\Delta t}}{\sqrt{k}} = \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_i}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
By the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) this converges to a gaussian variable, from where you get form of the law on your book.

For the technical detais, look the Wikipedia article referenced.